# Activating Python virtual environment on Windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, powershell, virtualenv

Note: People have marked this as a duplicate of another question but it is not. There is something off about my virtualenv and I have not been able to resolve it. It might have to do with how Visual Studio sets it up.

I have been following along with this excellent [tutorial on flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

I ran into a problem when I tried to activate the virtual environment on Windows. How do you execute `$ venv\Scripts\activate`? Is this supposed to be from the command prompt or Powershell?  I have used Visual Studio as my IDE. It creates for you a VS solution that has a basic flask app to start with. In the process of creating the app it asks you to create a virtual environment.  It creates that virtual environment in a directory similar to the one shown in the tutorial. `\venv\Scripts` exits but it does not have a file or executable called "activate".

here is the content of the Scripts folder:

> api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
>
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
>
> concrt140.dll msvcp140.dll pyexpat.pyd python.exe python3.dll
>
> python36.dll pythoncom36.dll pythonw.exe pywintypes36.dll select.pyd
>
> sqlite3.dll tcl86t.dll tk86t.dll ucrtbase.dll unicodedata.pyd
>
> vccorlib140.dll vcomp140.dll vcruntime140.dll winsound.pyd
>
> xlwings32.dll xlwings64.dll
>
> _asyncio.pyd
>
> _bz2.pyd
>
> _ctypes.pyd
>
> _ctypes_test.pyd
>
> _decimal.pyd
>
> _elementtree.pyd
>
> _hashlib.pyd
>
> _lzma.pyd
>
> _msi.pyd
>
> _multiprocessing.pyd
>
> _overlapped.pyd
>
> _socket.pyd
>
> _sqlite3.pyd
>
> _ssl.pyd
>
> _testbuffer.pyd
>
> _testcapi.pyd
>
> _testconsole.pyd
>
> _testimportmultiple.pyd
>
> _testmultiphase.pyd
>
> _tkinter.pyd

I got all the way to [data migration section](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) but here I need to run the `(venv) $ flask db migrate`

I am at a loss on how to get into the virtual environment to run this.

Comment: The documentation also explains how to activate virtualenv : https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

Comment: It seems that this due to a bug in Python Tools For Visual Studio. It only happens when you try to create an Anaconda virtual environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my CheatSheet when I install python on windows via PowerShell.

First install python 2.7x from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Then add the Python and Scripts folder to the path variable (system wide)

```
# Add Python and Python Scripts to path
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
$PythonPath = "C:\Python27"
$PythonScriptsPath = "C:\Python27\Scripts"

if ($env:Path -notlike "*$PythonPath*") {
    $env:Path = $env:Path + ";$PythonPath"
}

if ($env:Path -notlike "*$PythonScriptsPath*") {
    $env:Path = $env:Path + ";$PythonScriptsPath"
}

# Save to machine path
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "Path", $env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )

# Check machine path
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Then install virtualenv via pip

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Activate an virtualenv

```
virtualenv venv
. .\venv\Scripts\activate
```

> If using Powershell, the `activate` script is subject to the execution policies on the system. By default on Windows 7, the system’s excution policy is set to `Restricted`. In order to use the script, you can relax your system’s execution policy to `AllSigned`, meaning all scripts on the system must be digitally signed to be executed. As an administrator run: `Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned`

Deactivate a virtualenv

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Thanks. You are in an environment where you get the unix shell(ish) $. Powershell gives me a dos(ish) PS C:\Users\Me> instead.

How do you get to that $?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The dollar sign is a variable in PowerShell. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6

I've added a screenshot of my environment: https://prnt.sc/ida85x

Comment: Thanks for the details. It appears that my problem is due to a bug in Visual Studio when creating an Anaconda environment. Since your cheat sheet is so awesome, I am marking this as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: What if I needed to run these commands from powershell script? I was trying to figure how to create & activate virtualenv from powershell and then run python script inside the virtualenv, but I can not figure out how to run python script AFTER  the virtualenv is activated.

Answer (score -2):

path_to_env/Scripts/activate

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that both on the command prompt and on Powershell and get: 'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

There is no file or executable called activate in the Script directory

Comment: That means virtual environment is not installed properly.

Comment: it doesn't work